# Visual Studio 2012 Project Templates and Nuget and Update All

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, project-template

What I currently do: When I start up a new project in VS 2012 and pick MVC 4 Internet Application.  The first thing I do is go to the Nuget Package Manager and click the "Update All" button.

My question is:  Is there a way to take this newly updated project and make THIS a template or is there a place to get updated project templates?

Why I am asking:  I want to do this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a duplicate: [Update default nuget packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532909/update-default-nuget-packages)

I blogged about how to update NuGet packages consumed by project templates over here: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/update-project-template-to-latest-nuget-packages

Comment: Thanks!  I was searching for it the wrong way.  As a dev for 20+ years, Nuget is new to me and it is awesome.   I really like the idea of making my own templates.  Thanks again Xavier.