# How to have the latest nuget packages for a new project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

When I create a new project (i.e. MVC project) in Visual Studio 2013 / 2015 I have to go to nuget manager and update all packages to the latest versions. I want to update templates to have the latest versions of packages. Is it possible?

Comment: check this post , you can use that script..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/31276284/4678027

Comment: I want to update templates, not update all packages after create a project...

Comment: you mean project template ?

Comment: Yes, project template

Comment: see this post  then ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532909/update-default-nuget-packages